# Redirect from subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to do is to redirect the user who use for example `en.domain.com/blog`
to `domain.com/blog` I have three languages en/es/fr

I tried something like this For the english but its not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.domain\.com\/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Anyhelp
Thanks

Comment: Do you want both `en.domain.com/blog`, `es.domain.com/blog` and `fr.domain.com/blog` to redirect to `domain.com/blog` ? Also, you said **redirect** but in your code you're trying an internal rewrite. What do you want ?

Comment: yes, all of them to domain.com/blog

Comment: sorry I thought they are the same :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en|es|fr)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your document root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /blog$1 [R,L]
```

The HTTP_HOST does not contain any URI (path part). Also you have to switch the "rewrite engine" on.

Comment: but I want to redirect only the people who visit en.domain.com/blog not en.domain.com

Comment: Well, it depends where you put the .htaccess file. The original one had to be in the blog folder, this need to be in the document root